# jQuery jScrollPane does not appear (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jscrollpane

i try to use jScrollPane on my own WordPress Theme. But it does not appear. i dont know, what the problem is... i see only the old grey standard scrollbar

**functions.php**

```
//Register jScrollPane
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jscrollpane_libs' );  
function jscrollpane_libs()  
{  
    // Register each script, setting appropriate dependencies  
    wp_register_script('jscrollpane', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js');
    wp_register_script('mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.mousewheel.js');

    // Register each style, setting appropriate dependencies 
    wp_register_style('jscrollcss',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.jscrollpane.css');
}

//Register jQuery 1.8
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
if(!is_admin()) { 
     wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

**header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $('.nivo-caption').jScrollPane();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What does it show in developer tools  "console"?

Comment: the console is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) also in your header? Try replacing `wp_register_script()` with `wp_enqueue_script()` in your functions.php file to check and see if it is working.

Update: it now appears that the scripts are being included properly, perhaps the issue may be that the content in your caption box is dynamic. jScrollPane has an option to [reinitialize](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html) the content box once something has changed. Perhaps your code would look similar to the following.

```
$(function() {
    var pane = $('.nivo-caption');
    pane.jScrollPane();
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    $('.nivo-control').click(function(){
        api.reinitialise();
    });
});
```

Comment: i change it in my functions.php: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jscrollpane_libs' );  
function jscrollpane_libs()  
{  
    // Register each script, setting appropriate dependencies  
    wp_enqueue_script('jscrollpane', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.mousewheel.js');
 
    // Register each style, setting appropriate dependencies 
    wp_enqueue_style('jscrollcss',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/scroll/jquery.jscrollpane.css');
}` but i have the same problem

Comment: Are you able to post a link?

Comment: i mean the 5th caption box in the slider

Comment: thanks for your time. i copy your code into my header.php. but nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [**don't dequeue WordPress bundled jQuery**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440).

In `functions.php` it should go like:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jscrollpane_libs' );  

function jscrollpane_libs()
{
    $js = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js';
    $css = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css';

    wp_register_script( 'jsp-lib', "$js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" );
    wp_register_script( 'jsp-mouse', "$js/jquery.mousewheel.js" );
    wp_register_script(
        'jsp-main', 
        "$js/demo.js", 
        array( 'jquery', 'jsp-lib', 'jsp-mouse' ), // <--- Dependencies
        false,
        true // <--- In footer
    );

    wp_register_style( 'jsp-css', "$css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jsp-main' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jsp-css' );
}
```

And the file `demo.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) // <---- Proper enclosure to use in WordPress
{
   $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

And our post has this HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
        eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
        mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
        consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
        bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
        semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
        mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
        quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
        eu lacus semper viverra.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your time! :) if i use your code, i get the following errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [***]/itandgaming/wp-content/themes/itandgaming/css/demo.css?ver=3.6.1
Uncaught ReferenceError: djQuery is not defined

Comment: This file exist `http://example.com/itandgaming/wp-content/themes/itandgaming/style.css` , the one you linked does not.

Comment: i removed the "d" in the demo.js to "jQuery" (if it was a mistype) now i have only the 404 error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://example.com/itandgaming/wp-content/themes/itandgaming/css/demo.css?ver=3.6.1 i dont know what you are exactly mean with demo.css, i have no demo css and the scrollbar still not work :/

Comment: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ in the how to stays only in need the "jquery.jscrollpane.css"

Comment: There's no element with the class `nivo-caption` in your page, this doesn't affect nothing: `$('.nivo-caption').jScrollPane();`

Comment: Sorry, but I tested the jScrollPane in my machine using this exact code and it works. I updated the Answer with the HTML I tested and also removed the `demo.css`, as it was just for testing. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: hm i tried something with the codes, but nothing works really. i think i use an other plugin... hm i can't explain why it wont work